# Is there a way to oraginize imports in vs code without removing 'react import'

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to organize imports on saving a file. So I updated vs code settings to always organize imports when saving a file.

But it also removes `import React from 'react'`.

So react gives me this error `'React' must be in scope when using JSX`.

For eg,

```
import React from 'react'

const Temp = () => {
  return (
    <div>Temp</div>
  )
}

export default Temp
```

organizes to

```
const Temp = () => {
  return <div>Temp</div>;
};

export default Temp;
```

This is my react version - `"react": "^16.13.1"`.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading react version? Since version 17 you can remove `React` import

Comment: I can't update React. This is a must because of a lot of other dependencies

Comment: I use prettier to format imports on save (but not remove them) and then use eslint to give warnings about imported but unused items. This approach might work for you.

Comment: That's fine. But I want to auto remove unused imports on save too. Also not remove React from imports.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `babel.config.js` file?

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                modules: false,
            },
        ],
        ['@babel/preset-react', { runtime: 'automatic' }],
    ],
};
```

I have a project that uses this and it works pretty fine.

Refer the [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#manual-babel-setup) for configuration.

Comment: Will it effect how the project compiles on production?

Comment: Not entirely sure. But you can customize it for different environments if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I don't know about babel . Also I can't change anything major just to organize some imports.